# Facebook Video Upload Issue Android

Tags: android, facebook, post, video

Wherever i am trying to upload the video on facebook. Facebook will give me following error in response.

Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, error

```
Code: 100, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) No permission to publish the video}}


private void PostVideo(byte[] VideoBytes, String path) {

        String url;
        url = "/me/videos";

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Loading data", "Please wait", false, false);

        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (token != null) {
            Bundle param = new Bundle();
            param.putByteArray("video." + getFileExt(path), VideoBytes);
            param.putString("description", title+"\n"+description);
            new GraphRequest(token,url, param, HttpMethod.POST, new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e("New Post", "Res =" + response.toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    if (response != null && response.getJSONObject() != null && response.getJSONObject().has("id")) {
                        Log.e("New Post", "Success");

                        edittext_title.setText("");
                        edittext_description.setText("");

//                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Video posted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error in posting Video.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Well that would most likely have to do with the recent removal of `publish_actions` permission, I suppose …

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that you have to request a video_upload permission. First, call below code to give a permission.

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    //If the session is open
    if(session.isOpened()) {
        //Get the list of permissions associated with the session
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        //if the session does not have video_upload permission
        if(!permissions.contains("video_upload")) {
            //Get the permission from user to upload the video to facebook
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("video_upload"));
            session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        }
     }
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Session is not importing into my project. Can not find in facebook sdk i guess.. Can you tell me which sdk version you are using of facebook?

Comment: I'm using this sdk : compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

Comment: Have you got it?

Comment: No..Still have the same issue.